# Foxpro 2.6a for Windows RegFn call

Tags: c#, dll, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have to replace an existing dll call that is registered and called using RegFn and CallFn respectively.

I am trying to write the dll using C# in the hope that as long as the function signature match and the dll is in the right place it will work.

so

```
pnHndl= RegFn("CALCULATE", "I", "I", "AJons.DLL")
pnRetVal = CallFn(pnHndl, 0)
```

My code is as follows:

```
[Guid("EAB7C2CD-2471-4BDA-90E9-F70403BAA557")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class AJons : _AJons
{

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public int CALCULATE(int value)
    {
        return value * 2;
    }

}
```

Foxpro doesn't play ball I just get 'could not load library AJon.dll'

Does anyone have any experience here?

Cheers.

Comment: Is RegFn built into fp 2.crap?

Comment: not built in.. no.. foxtools.fil provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, those really old RegFn and CallFn are for calling Win32 native Dlls - completely different from COM.

What you need to create a Win32 dll that will work with those functions is C++.

What you should do (if you HAVE to keep using FoxPro) is at least use the latest version of VFP.

written on my iPhone

### Update 1

1) Just in case I wasn't clear, you **cannot** make this kind of DLL from .NET.

2) Have a look at this link [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/dll.aspx) for a very simple example of how to write a Win32 dll.

Comment: Would such a dll need to be 16bit also?

Comment: As evident in the name, Win32 DLLs are 32 bit. I have updated the answer with a link to a simple example.

Comment: I have identified a more central interception point for my code. Although your answer appears sound I am reluctant to mark as 'the answer' as I haven't test it! If I do, I will.

Comment: I don't think the asker will see this comment - you should add your comment to his question instead.

Comment: The asker didn't see the comment! Sorry, i'll start a campaign to accept the answers.